# SQL: Is it possible to assign a name to a joined table

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have the following two tables:

Shop:

```
Name        |   Country 
Pharmacy        Japan
Green Vine      Italy
Red Palace      Morocco
La Pizza        Italy
Nature Shop     Japan
Medical 100     Japan
```

Info:

```
Name      |   Category   | Price
Pharmacy      Health       Cheap
Green Vine    Dining       Medium
Red Palace    Dining       Expensive
La Pizza      Dining       Cheap
Nature Shop   Health       Medium
Medical 100   Health       Expensive
```

The attribute 'Name' in Info is a foreign key which references the attribute 'Name' (primary key) in Shop.
I want to write a query that outputs all the Names that belong to a category where all the countries are the same (e.g. all the stores in the Health category are in Japan). E.g. the output would be:

```
Name        |   Country    |    Category
Pharmacy        Japan           Health
Nature Shop     Japan           Health
Medical 100     Japan           Health
```

I have the following code to join the two tables:

```
select Shop.Name, Country, Category from Shop, Info where 
(Shop.Name=Info.Name);
```

I am not sure how I can compose the rest of the query, because I had to join two tables, so the resulting table doesn't have a name. Is it possible to assign a name to the table that results when you join the tables Shop and Info on the attribute name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When writing queries, *always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.  I also recommend table aliases.

Your query is as easy as adding two `WHERE` conditions, so:

```
select s.Name, s.Country, i.Category
from Shop s join
     Info i
     on s.name = i.name
where s.Country = 'Japan' and i.Category = 'Health';
```

Of course, you don't need to return the country and category . . . because you know what these are.  If that is the case, then `exists` might be more appropriate:

```
select s.Name
from Shop s 
where s.Country = 'Japan' and
      exists (select 1
              from Info i
              where i.name = s.name and
                    i.Category = 'Health'
             );
```

Comment: Suppose that I have another category called 'Technology' in the table 'Info', and all the countries within it are 'Japan'. The above query only selects tuples where the Country is Japan and the Category is Health. How can I generalise the above query so that I can get the names in all the categories, not just Health, where all the countries within it are 'Japan'?

Comment: @cano980 . . . New questions should be asked as *new* questions not as comments.

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is to use your join result into a new [cte](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
with HealthStoresInJapan as (
    select s.*, i.Category
    from Info i 
    join Shop s on i.Name = s.Name
    where s.Country = 'Japan' and i.Category = 'Health'
)

select * from HealthStoresInJapan
```